# Vuetify3 How to define theme settings

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I have some troubles to define theme settings with the new vuetify 3.

Documentation example (for Vuetify3):

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

export default createVuetify({
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'myCustomTheme',
    themes: {
      myCustomTheme: {
        dark: false,
        colors: {
          ..., // We have omitted the standard color properties here to emphasize the custom one that we've added
          green: '#00ff00'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I did exactly the same (of course removing **...,** in colors), but got an error in chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Anyone know why this is happens? (I know that it is a new version and the documentation is still under development).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely a bug in Vuetify (it is `alpha` version after all). I've reported it in [`vuetifyjs/vuetify` Issue #13822](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/13822).

Version `3.0.0-alpha.6` requires a `theme.variables` object property defined to avoid the crash:

```js
export default createVuetify({
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'myCustomTheme',
    themes: {
      myCustomTheme: {
        variables: {}, // ✅ this property is required to avoid Vuetify crash
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also be aware of a couple issues with `colors`:

1. Primary color names in `colors` seem to be ignored, so you can't use `green`. Pick something like `greenish` instead.
2. Setting `colors` seems to wipe out the unspecified default colors (which is likely undesirable), so they should be included in the custom setting.

```js
myCustomTheme: {
  colors: {
    // green: '#xxx', 1️⃣
    greenish: '#xxx',

    // 2️⃣
    background: '#ccc',
    surface: '#212121',
    primary: '#00ff00',
    'primary-darken-1': '#3700B3',
    secondary: '#03DAC5',
    'secondary-darken-1': '#03DAC5',
    error: '#CF6679',
    info: '#2196F3',
    success: '#4CAF50',
    warning: '#FB8C00'
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vuetify3?file=src/vuetify.js)

Comment: Thank you very much! And thanks for the clarification of the colors, hopefully they fix that because sometimes you don't want to define all

Answer (score 2):

### What worked for me in Vue3 and Vuetify 3

***[ solved ]***

I went to the SRC folder and the Plugins folder, editing the file that comes by default in vuetify.js

*file: src/plugins/vuetify.js*

```
// Styles
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'

// Vuetify
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

export default createVuetify({
  // https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'light',
    themes: {
      light: {
        dark: false,
        variables: {}, // ✅ this property is required to avoid Vuetify crash

        colors: {
          //green: '#00ff00' // cannot use primary color names here, so use a custom color name (such as 'greenish')
          greenish: '#03DAC5',

          // Workaround: Custom colors seem to erase default colors, so we need to include the default colors (of `light` or `dark` theme)
          background: '#fbfbfb',
          surface: '#212121',
          primary: '#00ff00',
          'primary-darken-1': '#3700B3',
          secondary: '#03DAC5',
          'secondary-darken-1': '#03DAC5',
          error: '#CF6679',
          info: '#2196F3',
          success: '#4CAF50',
          warning: '#FB8C00'
        },
      },
      darkBlue: {
        dark: true,
        variables: {}, // ✅ this property is required to avoid Vuetify crash

        colors: {
          //green: '#00ff00' // cannot use primary color names here, so use a custom color name (such as 'greenish')
          greenish: '#03DAC5',

          // Workaround: Custom colors seem to erase default colors, so we need to include the default colors (of `light` or `dark` theme)
          background: '#111928',
          surface: '#212121',
          primary: '#00ff00',
          'primary-darken-1': '#3700B3',
          secondary: '#03DAC5',
          'secondary-darken-1': '#03DAC5',
          error: '#CF6679',
          info: '#2196F3',
          success: '#4CAF50',
          warning: '#FB8C00'
        },
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Then in my v-toolbar file create what the official vue documentation says
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/

*this my componente navbar in file: src/components*

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-btn @click="toggleTheme">toggle theme</v-btn>
    ...
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'

export default {
  setup () {
    const theme = useTheme()

    return {
      theme,
      toggleTheme: () => theme.global.name.value = theme.global.current.value.dark ? 'light' : 'darkBlue'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Hope I helped, because I felt like there wasn't as much information about the implementation.